# How do redirect by click item in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

There is HTML code:

```
<div class="item" data-url="link"></div>
<div class="item" data-url="link"></div>
<div class="item" data-url="link"></div>
```

In Jquery I can do:

```
$('.item').click(function () {
   var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
   redirect(url);
});
```

How do this in Angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this i just create an example. you can modify as per your requirement. Then
want to configure the `$location`service in your controller.

```
//i just create an example you can modify as your requirement
$scope.redirect = function(){    
       $location.path("/route");
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div class="item" data-url="link" ng-click='redirect()'>redirect</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you don't want to wrap your `<div>`s in an `<a>`, you can just add an `ng-click` attribute to them and redirect in your controller code. If your redirect is internal, you should look into using the `$location` service, otherwise use the `$window` service.

Comment: @sahe: once you are done with writing a method in your controller you can move the code to a directive something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/22592535/537079